# How to fix incorrect arrow issues in MetaTrader 4 running through Wine?

Tags: wine, fonts

After installing Wine and updating to v1.5.24, I installed MetaTrader 4 trading program.

But after that I found that the all the arrows in MetaTrader are drawn in an incorrect way.

Following screenshot shows the problem in drawing the arrows:

[image: PIC showing the problem in drawing the arrows.]

How do I solve the issue of incorrect arrows?

Comment: sometimes it is enough to copy windows/Fonts/webdings.ttf
and windows/Fonts/wingding.ttf

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to fix the problem:

1. Install Wine if it's not already installed (you obviously have it installed if you are running MetaTrader):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   ```

   Once Wine is installed you need to configure it. This is pretty easy. As a normal user (Not Root!) run `winecfg` from a terminal and it should set itself up. If you want to do any more configuration or tweaking, have a look around the tabs, but for now I suggest keeping it as default.
2. From a valid windows installation, copy over all the fonts into your wine installation. It also assumes you told Ubuntu to mount your windows partition in `/windows`:

   ```
   cp /windows/WINDOWS/Fonts/* ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/fonts/
   ```
3. Copy two needed DLL files from your valid windows installation:

   ```
   cp /windows/WINDOWS/system32/mfc4* ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/
   ```
4. Download `mt4setup.exe` from your favorite broker.
5. Install MT4.

---

Source: PDF files provided at [Ubuntu Forums Thread Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9674542&postcount=5)